# Firebase Admin Invalid Token

Tags: node.js, flutter, firebase-admin

I have this Error when I am trying to access a protected route with a auth google token.
hire is the error

```
{
    "code": "auth/argument-error",
    "message": "Firebase ID token has invalid signature. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens for details on how to retrieve an ID token."
}
```

I'am using nodejs on the server, the Api work well with postman but when i trying to access the same route in my flutter app i have this => as error: `403 message:{"error":"UnAuthorized"}`
Is there any one who has a solution???

Answer (score 0):

I have the answer, it was my mistake. 
In the header of the request I forget to startwith "Bearer tokenId...." in flutter app.